.NET Web API: Reorder Request best practices
This is the situation: there is a client that sends to my .NET web api

an HTTP call to open a new session
then sends a lot (let us say 100) of http calls with a payload all at the same time (+-)
and once the last call has been answered, its does one final HTTP call to stop the session.

The problem I have now is that in step 2 all these requests (can) arrive out of order. Each request has in its headers a sequence number so I do know which one to handle next. I was trying to implement Middleware to temporarily ignore an out-of-order http request, but it all seems to become a bit dirty.
The question is not really a coding one here, but rather one for best practices. I start to have the feeling that this is in general a bad idea.

Middleware maybe not a good way for it is out-of-order. Use a message queue that ensures order processing, such as RabbitMQ. The client can send messages to the queue, which guarantees order and processes them sequentially. Your backend service can then consume messages from the queue in the correct order.
